# select specific strings inside a DIV and format it

Tags: jquery, css, html

A sample text inside a div:

```
I am at the first line.
I am at the second line.
I am at the third line.
I am at the end of the first paragraph.
```

Problem:
I want to make a script that will make:

> 1. All "first" will be colored blue
> 2. All "second" will be colored green
> 3. All "third" will be colored red and BOLD

[Please see the non working code here..](http://jsfiddle.net/rickroydaban/y7ept/)

Added a link for the code

Comment: Where is your code?  People here will help you but not write code for you.

Comment: To clarify: You have some plain text in a DIV and you need to style the first, second and third sentences (no matter how many sentences come after the first 3)? Can the sentences end in something other than a period? As user1743214 suggests, do you have control over the text? Can you pre-wrap that text in HTML elements? Also, as Steve-Wellens suggests, can you provide any markup or code? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
$(function(){   
  $('#text').attr('value','first').css('color','#0000FF');
  $('#text').attr('value','second').css('color','#00FF00');
  $('#text').attr('value','third').css('color','#FF0000');
  $('#text').attr('value','third').css('font-weight','bold');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this will be almost impossible to achieve and if worked for one article or paragraph it wont work for the other ..
in my point of view the only solution will be including an html markup that will define those and then apply the jquery code for them ,

```
<p class='paragraph'>
<span class='firstline'>This is the first line.</span>
<span class='secoundline'> This is the second line. </span>
<span class='thirdline'> This is the third line.</span>
<span class='endparagraph'>This is the end of the first paragraph.</span>
</p>
```

now in the jquery part you can do something like

```
$(function(){
  $('.firstline').css({'color':'blue' , 'font-weight':'bold'});
  .....

})
```

Comment: Those texts are inside a div. Here:

<div>
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
This is the third line.
This is the end of the first paragraph.
</div>

Comment: sorry but how am i to know that ... other than that it doesnt matter if they are inside a div or what ever , you just need to put the correct markup

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jQuery `:nth-child` selectors. You can apply styles using css() or by adding classes to the paragraphs and styling them with CSS (which would be ideal).

I've created a JSFiddle with the two versions: http://jsfiddle.net/RJ8sC/5/. You just need to change the wrapper div ID to yours and you should be good to go.

Here's the jQuery code for quick reference:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#example p:nth-child(1)').css('color','blue');
    $('#example p:nth-child(2)').css('color','green');
    $('#example p:nth-child(3)').css({color:'red', 'font-weight': 'bold'});
});

// ALTERNATIVE USING CLASSES - THIS IS BETTER PRACTICE

$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#example2 p:nth-child(1)').addClass('first');
    $('#example2 p:nth-child(2)').addClass('second');
    $('#example2 p:nth-child(3)').addClass('third');
});
```